# Admin email handler with filter keeps sending emails

Tags: python, django, logging

I am trying to silence a specific error getting emailed through the `django.request` logger:

```
'django.request': {
    'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
    'level': 'ERROR',
    'propagate': True,
}
```

The filter `silence_invalid_header` is attached to the handler:

```
'handlers': {
    'mail_admins': {
        'level': 'ERROR',
        'filters': ['require_debug_false', 'silence_invalid_header'],
        'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
    }
}
```

This is the filter configuration:

```
'silence_invalid_header': {
    '()': 'mysite.logger_utils.SilenceInvalidHttpHostHeader'
}
```

And the filter class itself:

```
class SilenceInvalidHttpHostHeader(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        return 'Invalid HTTP_HOST header' not in record.msg
```

However, I keep getting emails.

Although `django.request` is set to propagate, it should propagate to Django's default logger `django` defined in `django.utils.log.DEFAULT_LOGGING`:

```
'django': {
    'handlers': ['console'],
}
```

And that hanlder just writes to the standard output:

```
'console': {
    'level': 'INFO',
    'filters': ['require_debug_true'],
    'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
}
```

So why do I keep getting emails with that error and how can I silence them?